Magento 2 : Configure Free Shipping Based on Subtotal Instead of Order Total
I enabled the free shipping method in Store > Configuration > Sales > Free Shipping.
However, it is currently applied based on the order total instead of the subtotal.

is there a condition on which free shipping is applied or is it just any ammout?
